# How to set basic authetication using only WebTarget in Jersey Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to set basic authentication for my Jersey client to authentication against the Server.
I want to set this authentication using only WebTarget (i.e without registering authentication in the client )

I tried the following code to set but it does not seem to work

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient(lClientConfig);
WebTarget webTarget  = client.target(uri);
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username,password);
webTarget.register(feature);
```

Could you please tell if its possible to do using only WebTarget ?

Comment: It actually does work. Do some logging and you will see.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Do you mean we need not to register HTTPFeature in the client to make it work ?

Comment: I mean that it works fine when I tested it registering the feature with the WebTarget.